# REGEXP_SUBSTR with a URL

Tags: sql, regexp-substr

I have a string in which I'm trying to extract a URL from. When I run it on [this RegEx site](https://regex101.com/r/H3TwSO/1), it works fine.

The Regex Pattern is: `http:\/\/GNTXN.US\/\S+`

The message I'm extracting from is below, and lives in a column called `body` in my SQL database.

```
Test Message: We want to hear from you! Take our 2022 survey & tell us what matters most to you this year: http://GNTXN.US/qsx Text STOP 2 stop/HELP 4 help
```

But when I run the following in SQL:

```
SELECT
body,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(body, 'http:\/\/GNTXN.US\/\S+') new_body
FROM
table.test
```

It returns no value. I have to imagine it's something to do with the backslashes in the URL, but I've tried everything.

The `new_body` output should read as `http://GNTXN.US/qsx`

Comment: `/pattern/` is a PERL style regex. In Oracle we use simple string as a pattern without additional `/.../`. That's why you do not need to escape them. You may check [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b20f523c4407ef51b2d447c28bd72988)

Comment: I cannot reproduce, this fiddle shows the matched text: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c03cf/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql you just need to escape the `\`

```
select body, REGEXP_SUBSTR(body, 'http:\\/\\/GNTXN.US\\/\\S+') as new_body
from table.test;
```

new_body output:

```
http://GNTXN.US/qsx
```